# Quick Sort in python with last element as pivot

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I have successfully tested my code.It works with last element as pivot.
However, when i try to count the total no. of comparisons made, it shows incorrect count.
I am counting through the global variable **tot_comparisons**.

Suggestions,where am i going wrong ?
Is there some silly error that i am making?

```
def swap(A,i,k):
    temp=A[i]
    print "temp is "
    print temp
    A[i]=A[k]
    A[k]=temp

def partition(A,start,end): 
    pivot=A[end]   
    pivot_index=start
    #pivot=A[end]


    for i in range(start,end):   

        #if A[i]<=pivot:
        if A[i]<pivot:
            print 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHhh'
            swap(A,i,pivot_index)
            pivot_index+=1
    #swap(A,pivot_index,end)
    swap(A,pivot_index,end)
    return pivot_index

def quicksort(A,start,end):
    global tot_comparisons
    if start<end:

        pivot_index=partition(A,start,end)
        tot_comparisons+=end-start
        print "pivot_index"
        print pivot_index
        print "ENDS"


        quicksort(A, start,pivot_index-1)

        #tot_comparisons+=end-pivot_index
        #quicksort(A, pivot_index, end)

        quicksort(A, pivot_index+1, end)

#A=[45,21,23,4,65]

#A=[21,23,19,22,1,3,7,88,110]
#A=[1,22,3,4,66,7]

#A=[1, 3, 7, 19, 21, 22, 23, 88, 110]
#A=[7,2,1,6,8,5,3,4]

temp_list=[]
f=open('temp_list.txt','r')
for line in f:
    temp_list.append(int(line.strip()))
f.close()
print 'list is '
#print temp_list
print 'list ends'

tot_comparisons=0
#quicksort(A, 0, 7)
quicksort(temp_list, 0, 9999)
#quicksort(temp_list, 0, len(temp_list))
print 'hhh'
print temp_list
print tot_comparisons
#print A
```

Comment: just tried your code, not working, `index out of range exception`

Comment: working successfully on my end..                                                                                  160361 is tot_comparisons output using my code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked that your quicksort works, though it's slightly different from the algorithm given in popular algorithmic texts, in which the last element is switched to the first and then the partitioning ensues. This may change the ordering of the sort which has an effect on the number of comparisons.

For example, your code:

```
def partition(A,start,end):
    pivot=A[end]
    pivot_index=start
    for i in range(start,end):
        if A[i] < pivot:
            swap(A,i,pivot_index)
            pivot_index+=1
    swap(A,pivot_index,end)
    return pivot_index
```

can be switched to:

```
def partition(A,start,end):
    swap(A,start,end)
    pivot=A[start]
    pivot_index=start + 1
    for i in range(start+1,end+1):
        if A[i] < pivot:
            swap(A,i,pivot_index)
            pivot_index+=1
    swap(A,pivot_index-1,start)
    return pivot_index-1
```

> Edited based on comment by OP.

Comment: I am counting through the global variable tot_comparisons

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment. Let me know if it works? I find your counter works correctly for me, and the result works as well, so the difference must be in the ordering of the elements.

Comment: Yes it works...so to understand: you have again used the first element of the array as the pivot(but ONLY after swapping it with the last element)...this ensures that last element is actually used as pivot...is that correct understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to declare global variable at the top of your script, check this working basic example:

```
inside = 0
def qsort(l):
    global inside
    inside += 1
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    pivot = l[-1]
    return qsort(filter(lambda x: x < pivot, l[:-1])) + [pivot] + qsort(filter(lambda x: x >= pivot, l[:-1]))

import random
l = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in xrange(100)]
print qsort(l)
print inside

>>> [1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 21, 22, 23, 26, 26, 28, 30, 30, 32, 32, 34, 35, 38, 40, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 49, 51, 51, 54, 55, 56, 56, 56, 58, 59, 60, 60, 61, 61, 62, 63, 65, 67, 67, 68, 68, 70, 70, 72, 73, 74, 77, 79, 80, 83, 85, 85, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99]
>>> 135
```

Comment: objective is not to get the working code..it is to understand where am i going wrong